# JQuery Simple Modal Confirm Not Continueing

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using a Jquery's Simple Modal but it's not working. The Yes/No box pops up but when it I No all is fine. But if I hit yes to Save changes the box disappears and it doesn't continue processing.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks,

Simple Modal Code:

```
   function YesNoBox(message, callback) {
$('#confirm').modal({

    position: ["20%",],
    overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
    containerId: 'confirm-container', 
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var modal = this;
       console.log(dialog)
        $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

        // if the user clicks "yes"
        $('.yes').click(function () {
            return true;
            modal.close();
        });

        // if the user clicks "no"
        $('.no').click(function () {

            modal.close(); // close the dialog
        });
    }
});
  }
```

The Call To it...

```
 function Logout()
 {
 var agree=confirm("Are you sure you want to Exit WOTTS?");
 if (agree)
      return true;
 else
      return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.yes').click(function () {
        return true;
        modal.close();
    });
```

when you "return" it stops the function there.

Comment: so are you saying remove the return? Because I tried that and neither worked!!

Comment: I removed the return true; when I click Yes on the modal it disappears but doesn't continue processing the form? Any reason why?

Comment: by "Processing", what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I have a save button. When the user clicks on it. The modal pops up and says Are you sure you want to save? When you hit No nothing happens. If you hit Yes, the modal disappears but the form doesn't finish processing/saving. It's like you hit NO! Any reason why this is doing this? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Here is how I call it from the save button: `onClick="return confirmYesNo();"` That goes the this function: `//Confirm Update Button.
function confirmYesNo()
{
var agree=YesNoBox("Are you sure you want to Save Changes?");
if (agree)
 return true ;
else
 return false ;
}` And then to the jquery function above...

Comment: console.log(dialog) should be -> console.log(dialog); ? I'm strugleing to understand your code, could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Again if you click on the image it would show a pop modal asking to Save Changes? If you click No it closes and all is fine. If you click Yes the box would close and do nothing but it should be processing and save the changes.